Calling a turbo stream from within another one
I have the two turbo stream views below:
# flash.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.append "flash", partial: "layouts/flash" %>

# create.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.update "header" do %>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</P>
<% end %>

# Flash goes here

Is there a way from within create to call the flash turbo stream?

.turbo_stream is a format extension, you can still do normal erb things:
# create.turbo_stream.erb

<%= turbo_stream.update "header" do %>
  Lorem Ipsum
<% end %>

# renders _flash.turbo_stream.erb
<%= render "flash" %>

# renders shared/flash.turbo_stream.erb
<%= render template: "shared/flash" %>


Thanks for the reply.

This should be possible, unless I misunderstood your question:
# create.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.update "header" do %>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</P>
<% end %>

# Flash goes here
<%= turbo_stream.append "flash", partial: "layouts/flash" %>

I.e. just call turbo_stream in the erb file as many time as you need.

Thanks. That works, but I'd rather avoid to have the same logic in two places.

Thanks for the feedback. But please explain why did you approve another answer saying basically the same thing? I'm always happy to improve my answers.

If I'm not missing anything, Alex suggested using <%= render template: "shared/flash" %>, which allowed me to keep the logic within a single file. This particular is missing from your answer.  Anyway, thanks again for finding the time to provide an answer.

Got it! Thanks a lot for the feedback!
